# React.js: Toggle className on click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have a `<Sidebar />` component which creates two `<TabLabel />` components.

I want to toggle the className `is-active`, if you click a tab label the class `is-active` should be added to the `<li>` element and removed on the other one.

There is no error ocuring, but the function `toggleClass()` doesn't seem to get invoked.

`<Sidebar />` Component:

```
constructor() {
  super();
  this.state = {
    active: 'generator'
  }
  this.toggleClass = this.toggleClass.bind(this);
}

toggleClass() {
  this.setState({active: 'code'});
}

render() {
  return (
    <div className="sidebar">
      <ul className="tabs-list">
        <TabLabel onClick={() => this.toggleClass()} active={this.state.active} text="Generator" />
        <TabLabel onClick={() => this.toggleClass()} active={this.state.active} text="Code" />
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

`<TabLabel />` Component:

```
render() {
  return(
    <li className={this.props.text.toLowerCase() === this.props.active ? "is-active" : null}>
      <h2>{this.props.text}</h2>
    </li>
  );
}
```

Comment: did you put a `console.log()` in the `toggleClass()` function to check whether it gets called?

Comment: yes, it didn't show up

Comment: Does `TabLabel` accept an `onClick` property? Does it do something with it?

Comment: In your case `onClick` will be just the part of `props`, you need to use it inside `TabLabel` component.

Comment: @rednaw No, the TabLabel Property doesn't do anything with it. I want to call the function `toggleClass()` in the `<Sidebar />` Component.

Comment: @MayankShukla I tried that too but then there are two different states of the active object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you keep `TabLabel` as dumb as possible and only propagate props to it?

Also, `TabLabel` needs to dispatch click changes so `Sidebar` knows which Tab has been selected.

Testability gets easier and you can even improve `TabLabel` rendering on `Sidebar` (such as using an array of tabs).

```js
class Sidebar extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()

    this.state = {
      active: 'generator',
    }
  }

  toggleClass(tab) {
    this.setState({
      active: tab,
    })
  }

  render() {
    const { active } = this.state
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="sidebar">
          <ul className="tabs-list">
            <TabLabel
              onClick={this.toggleClass.bind(this, 'generator')}
              active={active === 'generator'}
              text="Generator"
            />
            
            <TabLabel
              onClick={this.toggleClass.bind(this, 'code')}
              active={active === 'code'}
              text="Code"
            />
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const TabLabel = ({ active, text, onClick }) => 
  <li onClick={onClick} className={active ? 'is-active' : null}>
    <h2>{text}</h2>
  </li>

ReactDOM.render(
  <Sidebar />,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li.is-active {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much vor your answer, it was very helpful.
The only thing, which is not exactly clear to me is why you need a `key` property?

Comment: It's because I used an array and therefore each item within `map` needs a key prop. With that React knows which components have been selected, added, deleted or even modified as described [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys).

Comment: @Dario Also I added a `key` prop to `tabs` so you don't need to replicate for example `Code` and `this.props.text.toLowerCase()` every time you have to render `TabLabel`. `onClick` must know which tab has been clicked and your code only sets `code` as active tab.

Comment: @Dario I've just updated my answer so it matches your needs. Feel free to change it as you wish :)

Comment: @mersacarlin Thank you very much for your help. =)

Answer (score 1):

The `onclick` event will not propagate from inside `TabLabel` to the `onClick` handler. You need to set dedicated event prop and invoke it in the `TabLabel` component:

```
render() {
  const isActive = this.props.text.toLowerCase() === this.props.active.toLowerCase()

  return(
    <li onClick={() => this.props.onSelect(this.props.text)} className={isActive ? "is-active" : null}>
      <h2>{this.props.text}</h2> 
    </li>
  );
}
```

And in Sidebar:

```
toggleClass(active) {
  this.setState({active});
}

render() {
  return (
    <div className="sidebar">
      <ul className="tabs-list">
        <TabLabel onSelect={this.toggleClass} active={this.state.active} text="Generator" />
        <TabLabel onSelect={this.toggleClass} active={this.state.active} text="Code" />
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: But then I have to put the state in the `TabLabel` Component, right?

Comment: No, you don't need state in TabLabel. What is the problem you have?